# How to check if adview currently has ad running?

Tags: java, android, adview, admob

I currently have an **adView** that is launched whenever an activity is launched. I'd like to check if that **adView** already has an Ad running and if it does then it continues running that Ad , however, if it does not have an Ad running then I would like to load and Ad intho that **adView**.

This is the code currently:

```
private AdView mAdView;

mAdView = (AdView)view.findViewById(R.id.adViewEvent);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    adView.isShown();
```

this method return the status of ad whether it is showing to user or not you can use this. method in if else structure

```
if(!adView.isShown())
{
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: The answer seems to be technically wrong. The API says, quote: "Returns the visibility of this view and all of its ancestors
Returns:
True if this view and all of its ancestors are VISIBLE"